# How can I join two dataframes in a diagonal way using python?

Tags: python, pandas, rpa

I've tried using pandas merge, but I can't figure out how to join two tables at the following way:

[Tables in original format]
[image]

I want to make then look like this:

[Format that i need]
[image]

Comment: Try `pd.concat([df1, df2])`?

Comment: If your two dfs are already defined : df = df1.append(df2)

Comment: i've tried but this makes a table in a "normal" format (one under another)

Comment: @furquimmm please provide the data as **text** (ideally code to be copy/pasted to form the two dataframes)